# how to change a user control form a button on anther user control in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I try to switch usercontrol using another usercontol button and the second usercontol is set on main window of wpf application,

for example

1. main window of wpf application
2. user_list usercontrol
3. add_user usercontol

use `user_list` usercontrol button and switch `add_user` user control this usercontrol(add_user usercontrol) set on the main window

user_list.xaml[image]

2. add_user.xaml

Comment: Please, rewrite your question. It's unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of ways to achieve this without using additional framework:

- Have both user controls `add_user` and `user_list` in your `MainWindow.xaml` like this:

```xml
<Grid>
    <local:user_list x:Name="userList"></local:user_list>
    <local:add_user x:Name="addUser" Visibility="Hidden"></local:add_user>
</Grid>
```

And in your click event handler in your code-behind, switch the `Visibility` properties:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    userList.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    addUser.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    //Do other stuff like update data if needed
}
```

- Only have the main `UserControl` `user_list` in your `MainWindow` like this:

```xml
<Grid>
    <local:user_list x:Name="userList"></local:user_list>
</Grid>
```

And create and display a new `Window` to display your `add_user` control in the code-behind:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var window = new Window();
    window.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
    window.Content = new add_user();
    window.ShowDialog() //blocking call
}
```

- Instead of creating a new `Window` you could have your `add_user` control dynamically added to the visual tree of your existing `MainWindow`, like this:

```xml
<Grid>
    <local:user_list x:Name="userList"></local:user_list>
    <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl"></ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

And the code-behind:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    contentControl.Content = new add_user();
}
```